# Whats the url to get a Twitter share count

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, twitter

I'm trying to fetch my Twitter share count from my Twitter share button on my page, here is one url I tried but it seems to be dead.

Here is what I tried.

http://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http://stylehatch.co

Does anyone know a working url?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Twitter has finally removed their share count feature.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Twitter killed off the share counts a few months ago when they removed them from the embedded Tweet buttons. I may be wrong, but that's also what I believe to be the issue.

You may just want to not try to get share counts from Twitter whatsoever, seeing as they've made effort to kill it off anyway.

Comment: I'm looking at the gofundme pages and it seems like there is an active Twitter share button that will also show the total shares on the page. Is there something else going on here I'm not aware of or are they grandfathered in?

Comment: @user1186050 That's likely something custom that Gofundme cooked up internally. Not 100% sure, but that's the most likely scenario from what I know.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, I have both FB and Twitter share buttons on my page like gofundme. Is there something else you recommend or should I just use the FB share count as the total share count and not even worry about the Twitter stuff? Ort should I use something elsefrom Twitter like a like or something?

Comment: @user1186050 See [this post](https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-get-proper-twitter-share-count-for-a-url/53876/2) on the Twitter dev forums — they've killed off a way to get a proper count, however you can use Twitter's search API to get the past 7 days worth of Tweets containing your URL.

Comment: that doesn't help. Unless someone else has a better solution I guess I'll just use the FB share count and not even include the Twitter share count when I display it on the page.

Comment: That's the only thing you can do, since there is no API endpoint for this from Twitter.